# How to use singleton class with Win32::OLE in Perl?

Tags: perl, dll, com, singleton

I have a dll with a singleton class xxx_xxxx. How do I call it from Win32::OLE from Perl? I tried `Win32::OLE-> new("xxx_xxxx")` and it just crashed. But Win32:::OLE->GetActiveObject is OK. It is a Com visible dll...
Thanks.